# is there any way to unfork heroku database

Tags: postgresql, heroku

Is it possible to unfork (making master the forked one) heoroku database.

Just perform https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fast-database-changeovers and when i make it unfollow it becomes forked database (which should not happened so i posted the ticket to heroku) but for time being is there any way to promote the forked database as master one.

here is my pg:info

```
=== HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE (DATABASE_URL)
Plan         Ika
Status       available
Data Size    13.56 GB
Tables       23
PG Version   9.1.3
Created      2012-03-05 05:11 UTC
Forks        HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_MAROON

Status       available
Data Size    9.19 GB
Tables       23
PG Version   9.1.3
Created      2012-04-09 09:49 UTC
Forked From  HEROKU_POSTGRESQL_ROSE (DATABASE_URL)
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here.  A unfollowed DB is a fork.  Are you just suggesting that you want the fork to become the new master?

Comment: yes i want to make the forked (read only database) as master so can promote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure forks are not read-only and are equal terms with any other DB.  Therefore, if you want it to be your master DB simply promote it:

```
heroku pg:promote YOUR_FORK_DB_NAME
```

Comment: yes this is what i have done but this make my db as forked one. a couple of days ago heroku faced dedicated db api provisioning problem ... seem to be its ripple of that. i also posted a ticket to heroku hopefully they will help in it.

Comment: Yeah, Heroku support is probably your best bet here.

Answer (score 0):

A follower that is unfollowed becomes a fork, at the point in time of the unfollow.

This makes it a full read/write database of it's own.

To make it your 'master' database you use pg:promote to update DATABASE_URL.